# Saving empty fields to DB despite error checks in place?

Tags: java, sql

I have a database of appointments.  I want to update/modify an appointment while not allowing empty text fields.  The fields are all pre-populated with the original details of the appointment.

I have an error check to see if textfields are empty (there are more but this gets the idea across):

```
if (modifyAppointmentTitle.getText() == null || modifyAppointmentDescription.getText() == null)
{
Alert alert3 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert3.setHeaderText("INVALID ENTRIES");
alert3.setContentText("Please enter a valid value for each required field!");
alert3.showAndWait();
}
```

I then call my update function:

```
DBAppointments.updateAppointment(title, description, location, type, startToSave, endToSave, 
customerIDint, userID.getUserID(), contact.getContactID(), 
selectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
```

I should be getting an error about the empty text fields but nothing is happening and it is saving the modified appointment to the database still.  I'm thinking that since I'm pulling information from the database, the application is thinking the fields aren't empty since they are pre-populated? I have the same code for adding the appointment and it fires off correctly.

Comment: If you need SQL assistance, we need to see the problem SQL.

Comment: This is not how you check wether the string is empty, so for example your code still pass empty none null strings, I suggest using some well know helper classes like Apache StringUtils

Comment: The fields are not `null`, they are empty i.e. a String length of zero

Comment: @scarywombat I read your comment and thought "maybe something is still there" so I added another check.  "(modifyAppointmentTitle.getText() == null || modifyAppointmentTitle.getText().trim().isEmpty())"  By using the .trim().isEmpty(), I'm now getting the error check triggered.  Thank you for the nudge!

Answer (score 0):

After a slight nudge by a commenter, I began thinking that despite the textfield visually being empty, it may still have some underlying value.

I added an extra parameter:

```
if (modifyAppointmentTitle.getText() == null || modifyAppointmentTitle.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {}
```

Now the error message is being triggered.  Thank you guys for the help!